# Seemingly paradoxical probability in a game of odds

Tags: probability

If my friend and I were to both choose a number between $1$ and $10$, inclusive, at the same time, the probability that we pick the same number is $(\frac{1}{10})^2$. However, if my friend picks a number first and writes it down without showing me, the chance that the number I choose matches theirs would only be $\frac{1}{10}$.

Clearly, there's a difference between both cases but I can't quite put my finger on it. They seem the same to me (hence why I have used "paradoxical" in the title).

Any explanation is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: But the probability in your first case (which you said is $(\frac{1}{10})^2$) is still $1/10$. The probability that both your friend and you choose $5$ at the same time would be $(\frac{1}{10})^2$. (Requesting clarification in case I misunderstood the question)

Comment: Apologies if I was unclear. I meant to convey your second sentence (in which the probability is $(\frac{1}{10})^2$).

Comment: Then both of you choosing $5$ (probability $(\frac{1}{10})^2$) is just one case that you both pick the same number. You may also both pick the same number by both picking $1$, or both picking $8$ (each case with probability $(\frac{1}{10})^2$). (Requesting clarification in case I misunderstood the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If my friend and I were to both choose a number between $1$ and $10$, inclusive, at the same time, the probability that we pick the same number is $\left( \frac{1}{10} \right)^2$.

This is not correct. To see why, first observe that the total number of possibilities for the numbers you and your friend pick is $10^2 = 100$. You are successful if the number picked is the same: $1$ and $1$, $2$ and $2$, etc., up to $10$ and $10$. There are $10$ of these combinations, so the probability of picking the same number is $\frac{10}{100} = \frac{1}{10}$, not $\frac{1}{100}$.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Math beats blind intuition.